# cv2.imwrite not saving image

Tags: python, opencv

i've an issue with `cv2.imiwrite`

there are two folders, the `photos` is for normal image then the `gray` is folder to save the grayscale image from normal photo that already changed

i want to read a normal image and change to grayscale, and then save the grayscale

so this is my code

```
import cv2
import os 
import glob

count = 0

os.chdir('./photos')
for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite('./gray/grayscale{}.jpg'.format(count), image_gray)
    count += 1
```

the `image = cv2.imread(file)` have an array, and so the `image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLORBGR2GRAY)` have and array too. but why my `cv2.imwrite` code not saving the grayscale image to folder? i've searched answer in this forum but none of them answer my question. any answer would be appreciated. thanks in advance !

Comment: The path probably does not exist. Specifically, the `gray` directory does not exist so ensure that the folder exists first by either manually creating the folder or adding a condition to check if the path exists. If it doesnt exist then first create the folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, don't do this, especially `chdir()` etc.:

```
os.chdir('./photos')
for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite('./gray/grayscale{}.jpg'.format(count), image_gray)
    count += 1
```

Instead you may use much easier:

```
if not os.path.isdir( 'gray' ) :
    os.mkdir( 'gray' )  # make sure the directory exists

for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob('photos/*.jpg')):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite('./gray/grayscale_%03d.jpg' % i, image_gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that whether you're on designed directory

```
# Check current working directory.
retval = os.getcwd()
print "Current working directory %s" % retval
```

Make sure that 'gray' filder is existed or not. I think there's no problem with your code.